# Error: Class App\Kernel contains 1 abstract method and must therefore

Tags: symfony

[image]

> Error: Class App\Kernel contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface::registerBundles)

**Any help please its my first time trying to upgrade symfony from 3 to 4**

Comment: Check this SymfonyCast about upgrading from 3.4 to 4 https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-upgrade/sf34-deprecations

Answer (score 1):

Add the missing public method `registerBundles` to your `App/Kernel` class.

It default's to:

```php
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // register default bundles here - example:
        // new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        // [..] 
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        // [..]
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. One quick addition for anyone building retro software (as I am at the moment): Remember to return the `$bundles` variable at the end of this method :-)